# What are the graces at Weeping Peninsula pointing to?

Tags: ps4, elden-ring

I'm playing Elden Ring with latest update on my PS4. Now I'm at my first playthrough and I unlocked all maps and areas. I was checking if there is anything I missed before finishing the game and I noticed the graces at Weeping Peninsula are pointing at Castle Morne.

We know that graces point to Demi-gods and guide us to their location. For example the ones at Limgrave points to Godrick, Liurnia points to Rennala, Caelid points to Radahn and so on.

But what are the graces at Weeping Peninsula pointing to? There was no Demi-god at the end. It was just a bandit boss with that Game Of Thrones great sword. Am I missing something? Is there any Demi-god or great rune over there? I couldn't find anything in `Fextralife` or `IGN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Graces that give Guidance don't always point to "Demigods". They just point to bosses. For example, the [Leonine Misbegotten](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Leonine+Misbegotten) (which the Weeping Penninsula Grace is pointing to) is not a Demigod.

These bosses are generally part of a domain, or are tied to some part of progression, whether it be important items, or simply storyline progression.

> - Greater Enemies Bosses are found blocking progress or guarding important, powerful items and areas.
> - Demigods, Lords and Legends are the main Bosses of Elden Ring.

[Source](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Bosses)

Comment: then why it's only him? and he doesn't drop anything important right?

Comment: He helps the progression of [Irina's](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Irina) questline

Comment: but Irina is not that important. there are other NPCs that need progressions but there is no graces pointing toward them.

Comment: @BlackCrystal It's kinda optional but Irina's quest ends with her father Edgar, whose death one way or the other earns you Shabriri grape, which you would give to another NPC to get them to their final location, who then gives you the tip to open a certain door, which gives you the possibility to get a certain ending. Everything is optional if you know how to open the door, and you don't even need to kill the Leonine to get the grape (just kill Edgar) but since it's linked to an ending I guess that's why the grace points you there.

Comment: @BlackCrystal Leonine drops the Grafted Blade Greatsword, one of the few legendary armaments for the game. I'd say that makes them a plenty important boss!